# hook_schema install, but not uninstall

Tags: 7, entities, database

I can't figure how it is possible that the table I define in a hook_schema is created when I enable my module, but it isn't deleted when I uninstall the module (after disabling).

Drupal 7 documentation sais that the table should be automatically created and deleted when these events occours.

Here is the relevant part of the code inside `my_module.install`:

```
function my_module_schema(){
    $schema = array();
    $schema["my_module_table_xyz"] = array(
            ...
    );
    return $schema;
}
```

I don't know if it could be related to the difference between the modue name and the table name... or from the code present in the `hook_uninstall`... or something else...

Considering I also define a node type, the `hook_uninstall` should delete it (see following code), then `system` should automatically uninstall previously defined schema.

```
function my_module_uninstall(){
    ...
    node_delete_multiple(...);
    // delete custom fields
    node_type_delete(...);
    field_purge_batch(...);
}
```

What do you think about?
Thanks

**NOTE:** I use Drush to disable, uninstall and reinstall the module and I get the error `Table my_module_table_xyz already exist`.

---

**Update:** I just verified that the same code in a clean Drupal installation works as expected (table defined in hook_schema have been successfully removed).

In the "problematic" Drupal installation I also tried to explicit run `drupal_uninstall_schema("my_module_table_xyz")` at the end of the `hook_uninstall` (and I inserted a log instruction just after that line, to verify it runs without breaking), but nothing change. The table is stille there!

Any idea/hypothesis about will be really appreciated.

Comment: Disabling a module does not explicitly delete nodes created under that custom type - so yes, you would need to do this yourself. Though, most do not do this and instead leave it to the site administrators to make that call.

Comment: Also if you get a table installed, and then disable a module without the table going away, you will have issues re-enabling the module. In that case, delete the table manually, clear the cache, then enable the module. The table should appear without error. Disable the module, the table should be gone.

Comment: @Kevin thanks for your reply. I suppose that every time you wrote "disable" you meant "uninstall". I know that uninstalling a module doesn't delete provided nodes: this question is related to "hook_schema", so I'm not speaking of nodes (the code in my hook_uninstall have just been reported to exlude problem with it). Yes, I'm also aware that if enabling a module it says "unable to create an existing table" I have to manually delete that table, then I can proceed. My question here is: "what is the problem with my code?" and not "what trick I can opt for?"

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and finally I just manually did it in `hook_uninstall()`, I could find no other recourse.

```
function mymodule_uninstall() {
  $table_name = 'mytable';
  if (db_table_exists($table_name)) {
    db_drop_table($table_name);
  }
}
```

Hope this saves someone else some time.

Answer (score 1):

For recent usage in Drupal 8-9, this is the equivalent:

```
function mymodule_uninstall() {

  $table_name = 'mytable';
  $schema = \Drupal\Core\Database\Database::getConnection()
    ->schema();
  if ($schema->tableExists($table_name) ) {
    $schema->dropTable($table_name);
  }

}
```

Comment: Not sure why anyone downvoted this answer. The documentation shows the same code: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21database.inc/function/db_drop_table/8.9.x

Comment: @Beau Answer was probably downvoted because `db_drop_table()` is deprecated in drupal:8.0.0 and removed from drupal:9.0.0. Use `\Drupal\Core\Database\Database::getConnection()->schema()->dropTable()` instead. See https://www.drupal.org/node/2993033